# "This doesn't answer the question" reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts

Why isn't there a low quality post reason that is just "This doesn't answer the question"?

I see a non-trivial number of -3, -4 answers in my low quality queue with comments such as "this doesn't answer OP's question because of *some specific clause*". I don't necessarily have a reason to Recommend Deletion because the answer is just not relevant to the question, which to me qualifies it as low quality.

I don't like the "No Comment Needed" option because it might not be obvious that the answer doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Low Quality review queue is not about validating the *correctness* of answers.

The queue is there to weed out obvious low-quality content, stuff that you'd want to see deleted, or can be made okay enough to stay by editing.

If the answer is not addressing the question, you could always just leave a comment, or open the post with the provided link and downvote it. But if you cannot fix the answer by editing, and it doesn't require deleting, the post is 'good enough' to leave the voting to those that understand the subject matter.